# Modelling time based on Domain Driven Design principles

Tags: microservices, domain-driven-design, software-design, event-storming

I know this might be very abstract and the standard answer will be "it depends", but I would like to know from the experiences of the people who has modelled a complex application based on the Domain Driven Design, how much time did it take to model and design your application based on DDD principles and if possible, which process or steps took what amount of time?

I want to know if there is a set process to follow sequentially for designing our application based on DDD. My aim is to identify a step in the whole DDD process and provide a tool for simplifying that process.

Comment: The [DDD Starter Modeling Process](https://github.com/ddd-crew/ddd-starter-modelling-process) might be what you're looking for!